# Confirming compile time scripts execution in Xcode

Tags: xcode, bash

I am downloading data from a remote server using `curl` in Build Phases > Run Script. Downloading takes 5-15s, not that much, but multiple times a day it consumes considerable time. Is there a better way to skip a script than commenting it out? Ideally, it would be some kind of confirmation at compile time (e.g Do you really need to download X? y/n).

Comment: Make it a separate script, started manually. Downloading something from build phases cannot be a good idea.

Comment: Right, but it would be too easy to forget about the infrequently updated data. I prefer to keep it combined.

Comment: https://cantina.co/adding-interactivity-to-the-xcode-build-process/

Comment: @matt - after a while I have a selection dialog. This does exactly what I needed. Please 'answer' - I will accept this solution.

Comment: @Greg I mean that build should be predictable and giving always the same result from the same commit. If you are bringing external dependencies during build, that cannot happen. Unless you immediately commit them to your versioning system (e.g. using a version lock file). And that would be strange to do during build. The common solution is to use a build server with a separate job that will update your dependencies (e.g. once a day).

Comment: @Sulthan - in general I agree but the project downloads (on compile time) only raw data related to game levels. This is not critical data, which would affect the app behavior. In this sense, I think it is still secure to produce different builds each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t make the run script interactive in the console as far as I know. But you can use a shell conditional with an AppleScript interactive dialog, because AppleScript itself blocks while dialog is shown. See for example https://cantina.co/adding-interactivity-to-the-xcode-build-process/.

However, introducing uncertainty into a build is dangerous. Plus you’d never be able to automate the build. In my view you’d be better off flipping a custom build setting / environment variable.